# How to get rid of 'System.Web.DynamicData.DynamicValidator' is not defined error during web application conversion

Tags: dynamic-data

I am trying to convert a web project to Web Application. After conversion I am getting 'System.Web.DynamicData.DynamicValidator' is not defined error. Any idea how to solve this.

Three references needed for dynamic data are in the bin but still giving this error on designer files.

Comment: By Default, the "bin" folder is not part of a Web Application, they use the "References" folder instead.  The Bin folder still exists, (it is where the compiled assemblies go) but you should not see it in the solution explorer by default.  This might be the problem.  Make sure the references for DyDa are in the References "folder".

Also, in the .aspx file, is the namespace of the code behind file correct?  Check the value of the "Inherits" attribute of the <% Page declaration.  It should match the full name of the code behind file/class - including namespace.